# How to prove that the absolute difference of two numbers

Tags: inequality

which are within the same interval is equal or less to the difference of the marginal values of the interval?

I have the following inequalities:
$$a \le x \le b$$
$$a \le y \le b$$

How to prove that:
$$|x - y| \le b - a $$

I tried subtracting y from the first inequality to get:

$$a - y \le x - y \le b - y$$ but don't know how to conclude: $$| x - y | \le b - a$$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Multiply the second inequality with $-1$ and then add the two. Can you continue this reasoning? Also note that
$$\left|x\right|\le y\iff -y\le x\le y$$
for $y\ge 0$

Comment: So if I understood it correctly:

$$ a \le x \le b $$
$$ a \le y \le b $$
$$\implies$$
$$ a \le x \le b $$
$$ -a \ge -y \ge -b $$
$$\implies$$
$$ a \le x \le b $$
$$ -b \le -y \le -a $$

$$ \implies  a - b \le x - y \le b - a $$

$$ a - b = - (b - a) $$

and by using $$ -p \le q \le p \implies |q| \le p $$

I get $$ |x - y | \le b - a $$

is that correct?

Comment: @Shirohige You are 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  Prove that

$$x-y \leq b-a \, \mbox{and} \, y-x \leq b-a \,.$$